# Getting error Cannot convert 'int' to 'char *'

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, turbo-c

I want to store name of states and their capital in 2D array like this

```
State     | Capital
----------|--------
Bihar     | Patna
----------|--------
Jharkhand | Ranchi
----------|--------
Gujarat   | Gandhinagar
```

I tried to do this by code below using Turbo C++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
   char capt[20];
   char stat[20];
   char capt_stat[5][2];
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      cin>>capt;
      cin>>stat;
      for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
      {
     strcpy(capt_stat[i][j],stat);
     strcpy(capt_stat[i][j+1],capt);
      }
   }
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
      {
         cout<< capt_stat[i][j]<<"  "<<capt_stat[i][j+1];
      }
      cout<<endl;
   }
}
```

but getting error Cannot convert 'int' to 'char *' in line 18 that is -

> strcpy(capt_stat[i][j],stat);

Kindly guide me what is wrong?

Comment: You have an array of five arrays of two characters, meaning you can only store five *one-character strings*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you for the guidance, yes now I understood the logic. Is there any way to store the capt and stat array in other array. Basically I need to check and display the capital name if user enter state name.

Comment: What the hell book are you learning from??  It must be decades old.  This isn't even valid C++.

Comment: Get a decent C++ tutorial and use `std::string`. And yes, get a recent compiler, there are several free ones available.

Comment: Dear all experts I am helpless i have to use this compiler only it is recommended by school. I also use codeblock but that is not acceptab;e by school

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `capt_stat[i][j]` to be of type `char *`.

Declare as

```
char capt_stat[5][2][20]; // 20 is the maximum length of each string
```

Comment: Thanx for considering my problem. but what about loop how I will construct the loop for this array?

Comment: Yes done but now question is for list of state and capital also I need 2D array like - capt[5][20] for this I used `cin.getline(capt[i],20);` and again getting same error on same line.

Comment: Bandypadhyay Thank you for all support. Work is done. but if will be thankful if you can tell me the logic behind using 3rd [] in capt_stat array as you told.

Comment: You can think like this: `capt_stat` contains 5 rows, 2 columns, and each cell contains 20 characters. So it is declared like that.

Comment: basically what i know this type of declaration means 3D array. So can I say that we can use 3D array for storing the name of 5 states and 5 captials of maximum 20 characters.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `capt_stat[i][j]` is a single `char` and not a string, which is expected by `strcpy`.